# Show white background when swapping is done then show the Image that is in stack

Tags: ios, animation, tinder, koloda

Actually i have used [this](https://github.com/Yalantis/Koloda) library for swap like tinder everything works perfect. but i need white background when swapping is done after some time it will show the image in curl animation .

any one has done this

Comment: can you explain more? can we see images of what's happening?

Comment: yes this is the image link https://github.com/Yalantis/Koloda/blob/master/Koloda_v1_example_animation.gif

Comment: In this link you can see while swapping left to right it will swap and the image that is inside (stack) will come upper. as i don't want to do this . when one swap it will show first white background and after some time it display image.. Now got my point what i want to asks @MohammadBashirSidani

Comment: you mean the acrd is white for some time until the image loads?

Comment: yes actually in this library all image is loaded just like stack but i need some second and then display the image.

Comment: are you getting the image asynhronously from the internet or you have them locally on your device?